# Как спозиционировать элементы один под другим, невзирая на высоту элемента?

Tags: html, css

Как имея следующую разметку, разместить элементы следующим образом:
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.photo {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  max-width: 160px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px 20px 20px 0;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="photo">
  <div class="photo__item photo__item_1"></div>
</div>
<div class="photo">
  <div class="photo__item photo__item_2"></div>
</div>
<div class="photo">
  <div class="photo__item photo__item_3"></div>
</div>
<div class="photo">
  <div class="photo__item photo__item_4"></div>
</div>
<div class="photo">
  <div class="photo__item photo__item_5"></div>
</div>
<div class="photo">
  <div class="photo__item photo__item_6"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

В данном случае на мой взгляд проще расположить все картинки в независимые столбцы, тоесть

```
<div class="photo_column">
  <div class="photo__item"></div>
  <div class="photo__item"></div>
  <div class="photo__item"></div>
  <div class="photo__item"></div>
</div>
<div class="photo_column">
  <div class="photo__item"></div>
  <div class="photo__item"></div>
  <div class="photo__item"></div>
  <div class="photo__item"></div>
</div> 

// и тд...
```

Особенно  хорошо в этом бы примере подошел CSS фреймворк  [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com), а так же предлагаю взглянуть на интересный плагин [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com).